# How to post picture, url and text with facebook graph api after July 2017?

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

[image]
I was previously able to make the above post using the parameters `message`, `link`, `name`, `caption`, `description`, `picture`

but since the facebook graph api got the latest update I am unable to post the same and I found that only `message` and `link` are posted and the rest (`picture`, `description` and `caption`) are dumped

[image]

How do I fix it? I am looking at the developers.facebook.com Docs but have not yet found anything.

**EDIT:**
According to this link [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.10/user/feed), it says it deprecated, but I haven't found any new/alternative method of making the above post.

Comment: Open Graph meta tags directly returned by the URL that you are sharing are currently the only way to specify those values.

Comment: @CBroe: I understand, but the old method is new deprecated, and hence my existing code is broken. Is this feature completely scraped or is there another way I can make those post?

Comment: cbroe already told you the only way. you have to use a unique url that includes the correct og data.

Comment: It is Open Graph meta tags only for now, so that however is in control over the URL that gets shared, is also in full control over these properties. This is part of an effort to fight fake news - and therefor leaving any open “loopholes” that would still allow to specify those dynamically at the time of sharing, would defeat the purpose.

Comment: They said in a recent blog post, that they are looking for other ways to make it possible for content publishers to overwrite those values, https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2017/06/27/API-Change-Log-Modifying-Link-Previews/ - but there is no news on that yet AFAIK, so for now it is OG meta tags only.

Comment: @Cbroe is right. Facebook has deprecated this feature from the API and from the Composer. There will be no alternative besides setting the OG tags directly in the content.

Answer (score 1):

At now there is only a solution as said, adding OG meta tags to your page.

Here you can find a valid guide to OG meta tags: https://blog.kissmetrics.com/open-graph-meta-tags/

Also useful is Facebook Developer Debugger to test your link page preview: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/